# How is window.postMessage() "secure"?

Tags: javascript

Please bear with me, I have only some web development experience. In the window.postmessage() documentation syntax is shown for listening for the event caused by postmessage() on the listening page. It is explicitly stated for security reasons that when the event listener is triggered, event.origin should be check to ensure it comes from an expected host. Typically done in the fashion:

```
if ( event.origin == somehostname.com) {}
```

Where I get confused is why a malicious user can't just pause the code using a breakpoint and modify the some hostname.com value. This same thing probably applies for the postmessage() call itsself as well for the target origin parameter. How does this provide any "security" when someone could just go edit the string value before it ever happens?

Comment: It’s not secure against the person running the JavaScript (nothing client-side is). It’s filtering out messages from any other site that person might have open. For other types of interactions, the same-origin policy is what protects websites (origins) from each other, but `postMessage` specifically exists to bypass that so you have to check yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your theoretical malicious user already has full access to the client-side of both websites. They don't need `postMessage` to access the data from either of them.

The Same Origin Policy is designed to stop a malicious *website* from accessing data from a different website using the credentials of the user of the browser (who has been tricked into visiting the malicious website).

`postMessage` can limit which origins are allowed to read the messages it sends, so if a website used it to send a message containing confidential information, it can mark the posted message as being for *some-trusted-website.com* which would prevent the malicious website from reading the message.

Comment: Let me see if I understand - we create a malicious website ready to receive some confidential info. Without the postmessage targetOrigin parameter, we could potential define an event listener as part of that malicious website. Therefore if targetOrigin was set to something like "*", it would be possible for our malicious website to receive that postmessage event and obtain that users info. You can't protect the actual client from changing the destination because they have all the info anyway. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

A "malicious" *user* could, certainly, make the client-side code do most anything they want, such as leaking information [that they already have access to] to another website, via `window.postMessage` *or* just by copying it and pasting it into an e-mail.

In your follow-up comment, you describe "we create a malicious **website** ready to receive some confidential info" as the threat model. That's a different thing entirely.

Yes, any website that's `window.postMessage` on sensitive data ought to do *at least* one of the following to be secure:

1. Check the `Referer` header to make sure that your parent is a trusted domain
2. Set `targetOrigin` to restrict recipients to those intended